# How a ListView continues scrolling without onScroll events after an onLongPress event

Tags: android

I'm using a `GestureDetector` to control the Touch events of a `ListView` via a `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`.

Watching the sequence of events generated, I've noticed two different behaviors depending on the time elapsed from the moment I touched the screen to the moment I started moving the finger on it.

If the time is short enough, I get this kind of sequence:

```
onDown          (touch)
onShowPress     (short waiting)
onScroll        (move)
...             (move)
onScroll        (move)
                (release)
```

If the time is longer, I only get this:

```
onDown          (touch)
onShowPress     (long waiting ...)
onLongPress     (... long waiting)
                (move)
...             (move)
                (move)
                (release)
```

No events seems to be detected by the listener in the second case while I move the finger, but, in either case, the content of the listview follows the movements of my finger.

What detects which event to allow the scroll of the listview in the second case?

The relevant code is this:

MainActivity:

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
gestureListener = new LV_GestureListener();
mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, gestureListener);
private ListView.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            MainActivity me = MainActivity.this;
            me.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
       }
};
```

LV_GestureListener:

```
public class LV_GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    public LV_GestureListener() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    ... event ...
    @Override
    ... event ...
}
```